# The navigation drawer on my page is not working as intended (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify navigation drawer in the navbar of my vuejs app. It open and closes properly. The issue is that none of the items inside are clickable. The correct functionality is that the items inside of the navdrawer should act as links to other pages. Currently, only the logout button is hooked up, but even that does not work.

My code:

```
 <template>
  <v-app-bar flat app>
    <!--Logo-->
    <v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase">
      <v-img src="@/assets/jawnfinder-logo.png" class="logo" contain max-height="75px" center></v-img>
    </v-toolbar-title>
    <!--Signup button and process-->
    <div v-if="!user"><Signin /></div>
    <!--Logout button-->
    <v-btn text target="_blank" color="yellow darken-2" v-if="user">
      <span class="logout btn" @click="logout">Logout</span>
    </v-btn>
    <!--Account button, maybe this should be it's own component. It's kinda long-->
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="blue--text" @click="account = !account" v-if="user">Account</v-app-bar-nav-icon>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="account" class="yellow" right temporary app>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/78.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>Account</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>Profile</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>Toolboxes</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>Settings</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title @click="logout">Logout</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

The navdrawer below should be bright yellow! Not a greyed out yellow. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, need to add a fix in navigation-drawer component

remove temporary  property from navigation drawer component

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="account" class="yellow" right **temporary** app>
```

Replace with

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="account" class="yellow" right app>
```

Comment: The temporary should only grey out the layer beneath the drawer, not the drawer itself.